# drawing logo with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw this logo with tikz 
[image]

What's the easiest way to draw it ?
Any advise ?

My MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12 pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{vertforet}{RGB}{153,202,67}
    \definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,172,95}
    \definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{7,196,234}
    \definecolor{Orange}{RGB}{245,178,31}
    \definecolor{Rose}{RGB}{238,28,131}
    \definecolor{Gray}{RGB}{109,119,125}


    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,trees,calc,positioning}

    %-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    \begin{document}
    %-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={white}]
       \filldraw[Gray](0.2,3.7) circle(0.8) ;
    \node[white] at(0.2,3.7){1};
    \filldraw[vertforet](-2,2) circle(1.2)node{2} ;
    \filldraw[Gray](4.6,1.3) circle(0.8)node{3} ;
    \filldraw[vert](-5.4,1.1) circle(0.6) node{4};
    \filldraw[bleu](1.3,2.3) circle(0.6)node{5} ;
    \filldraw[Rose](-2.7,-0.5) circle(0.4) node{6};
    \filldraw[bleu](1.3,0.3) circle(0.4) node{7};
    \filldraw[Rose](3,1) circle(0.6)node{8};
    \filldraw[Gray](-3,4.7) circle(0.6) node{9};
    \filldraw[Orange](-5.3,3.7) circle(0.5) node{10};
    \filldraw[Rose](3.5,-1.5) circle(0.4) node{11};
    \filldraw[vert](6,-0.25) circle(0.4) node{6};
    \filldraw[Orange](4.7,-1) circle(0.4) node{12};
    \filldraw[vert](3.5,-1.5) circle(0.5) node{13};
    \path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt](7,-1.5)to[bend left] (-6.5,1);
     \path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt](0.3,-5.5)to[bend right] (-1.5,-0.5) to(-5.2,3.2);
    \path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt] (-0.5,-1.5) to (0.8,1.7);
    \path[draw=Gray,line width =4 pt](-1.5,-0.5)--(-0.8,1.2);
    \path[draw=Gray,line width =4 pt](-0.8,1.2)--(-0.3,2.4);
    \path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt] (0.7,-4.5) to[bend left] (1.7,-1.5);
\path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt] (1.7,-1.5) to[bend left] (5.6,-0.25);
\path[draw=Gray,line width=4 pt] (1.7,-1.5) to(1.3,-.1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: If it is a logo and you've the right to use it, you should use the official version. (And if not, you shouldn't use it, probably.) Generally, I don't think redoing logos is entirely wise as they are official or semi-official symbols. Put it this way: *why* do you want to redo the work somebody else has already done?

Comment: @cfr I agree with your remark. This particular logo is an example of an awful tendency by some universities. They force everyone to print their logo on every possible document, but provide only a 251 × 212 jpeg image. Trying to reproduce it as a scalable image is tempting, I agree, but you shouldn't do so, Haouam. Have a look at the [Mentions Légales](https://www.univ-lille3.fr/universite/infos-pratiques/mentions-legales/) to try to get a contact for inquiring a better file.

Comment: The nonuniform thickness of the arc is a no go. You need to use something from Adobe suite or open source alternatives to draw it.

Comment: Wikipedia has an SVG version of the logo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Universit%C3%A9_Lille_Nord_de_France_(logo).svg (how they can claim that it has a low resolution I don't understand). You can probaby export it from an application like inkscape as a PDF and then `includepicture` it.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Good find. It would be good if Wikipedia actually provided the *source* for the image. They say you can get it from the university but don't say where. Agree about the resolution - that makes no sense.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that it would be legal for somebody to draw this here.

Comment: @cfr: Usually, if I need a logo, I try to find a PDF from as official a source as I can find, and then hope they have used a vector graphic I can extract (again, inkscape is a valuable tool for this work). I haven't had any luck with this one, however. On the other hand, I don't think the uploader on wikipedia holds any intellectual rights to the image, so using it is probably ok as long as one can use the logo at all.

Comment: It may be useful to know that there is a script to convert svg graphics into TikZ with inkscape.

Comment: I have a very bad png file and I know Ican do this with inkskape, photoshop indeed I can convert this file to svg. it's just a question to know if is it possible to do that with tikz!

Comment: As percusse pointed out above, the varying thickness of one of the lines is difficult to reproduce in tikz. Altogether, this type of graphic is not very well-suited to reproduction in tikz. For a logo, you'll want an exact reproduction of the shapes, not an approximation. While you could for example translate the paths from the SVG to tikz commands, there is little point in doing so.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Note the 'fair use' justification for the logo's use on Wikipedia. If you are in a jurisdiction which provides something similar and your use qualifies, you may be right. (But I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice!) But that Wikipedia can claim 'fair use' does not mean that everyone who reads the page can do likewise.

Comment: @cfr: Well, I'm assuming that Haouam is required and therefore allowed to use the logo by the university. As far as I understand, the person who uploaded the logo to wikipedia has no additional rights to it, so using that version should be fine also.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Oh, I see. Yes, that's true. But then I'd ask the university for a copy. it would be good to be sure where it is from, so to speak.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Based on the SVG version avalaible on Wikipedia, you can use Inkscape to convert it tp Tikz.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a TikZ version of the SVG logo taken from Wikipedia. The problem was that the paths in the logo use very condensed style (like `....16zm-.384-.423c-.493...` without spaces) that is not understood by `svg.path` library. So reformatting was necessary.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
  % les couleurs
  \definecolor{col1}{HTML}{3F464D}
  \definecolor{col2}{HTML}{F68712}
  \definecolor{col3}{HTML}{00A650}
  \definecolor{col4}{HTML}{3F464D}
  \definecolor{col5}{HTML}{66C430}
  \definecolor{col6}{HTML}{00A650}
  \definecolor{col7}{HTML}{F68712}
  \definecolor{col8}{HTML}{EC086D}
  \definecolor{col9}{HTML}{3F464D}
  \definecolor{col10}{HTML}{35B6ED}
  \definecolor{col11}{HTML}{EC086D}
  \definecolor{col12}{HTML}{00A650}
  % le logo
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale={1mm/1pt}]
    \fill[col1] svg {M 146.14 73.32 c -3.82 -2.19 -8.01 -3.31 -12.31 -3.65 c 1.04 0.6 2.55 1.67 3.67 3.08 c 1.11 0.39 4.08 1.34 6.2 3.86 l -0.25 0.21 c -1.81 -2.14 -4.26 -3.12 -5.59 -3.59 c 0.44 0.64 0.79 1.34 0.97 2.08 l -0.33 0.08 c -0.2 -0.84 -0.64 -1.64 -1.2 -2.35 c -1.36 -1.73 -3.39 -3 -4.28 -3.42 c -2.36 -0.13 -4.75 -0.03 -7.12 0.26 c 0.2 0.8 0.78 2.27 2.61 3.73 c 2.4 1.91 6.96 3.79 15.64 4.05 l -0.01 0.34 c -2.63 -0.08 -4.89 -0.31 -6.83 -0.64 c 0 0.37 -0.03 0.68 -0.05 0.83 c -0.04 0.26 -0.24 1.17 0.58 2.55 c 0.32 0.53 0.64 0.88 0.63 0.87 l -0.24 0.23 c -0.01 -0.01 -1 -1.08 -1.29 -2.4 c -0.66 1.9 -2.26 3.75 -5.08 4.35 l -0.07 -0.33 c 4.37 -0.93 5.25 -4.67 5.17 -6.17 c -4.29 -0.78 -6.98 -2.08 -8.67 -3.42 c -0.22 -0.17 -0.42 -0.35 -0.6 -0.52 c 0.4 0.89 0.81 2.13 0.81 3.63 c 0 1.28 -0.3 2.75 -1.15 4.37 l -0.3 -0.16 c 0.83 -1.57 1.11 -2.98 1.12 -4.21 c 0 -2.09 -0.83 -3.64 -1.26 -4.46 h 0 c -0.86 -1.05 -1.21 -2.01 -1.35 -2.6 c -1.6 0.21 -3.2 0.49 -4.77 0.85 c -0.19 0.47 -0.4 0.94 -0.64 1.4 c 0.31 4.12 1.08 10.07 6.64 13.81 l -0.18 0.28 c -5.46 -3.68 -6.41 -9.43 -6.75 -13.54 c -0.45 0.79 -0.96 1.54 -1.58 2.23 c -0.37 0.41 -0.76 0.83 -1.18 1.25 c -0.06 0.36 -0.11 0.81 -0.11 1.32 c 0 1.16 0.24 2.66 1.1 4.32 c 1.19 2.3 3.04 5.65 3.05 7.9 c 0 0.42 -0.07 0.81 -0.22 1.15 l -0.3 -0.14 c 0.13 -0.28 0.19 -0.62 0.19 -1.01 c 0 -0.76 -0.24 -1.68 -0.6 -2.66 v 0.12 c 0.01 1.85 -0.99 2.76 -2.02 3.46 c -1.04 0.71 -2.08 1.29 -2.42 2.39 c -0.9 2.94 -2.35 3.8 -3.17 4.74 l -0.25 -0.23 c 0.86 -0.92 2.32 -1.95 3.11 -4.64 c 0.36 -1.22 1.45 -1.79 2.54 -2.53 c 1.01 -0.7 1.87 -1.48 1.87 -3.19 c 0 -0.34 -0.04 -0.72 -0.14 -1.3 c -0.6 -1.37 -1.34 -2.77 -1.93 -3.9 c -0.24 -0.47 -0.44 -0.92 -0.6 -1.37 c -0.15 1.74 -0.93 4.38 -2.46 5.88 l -0.24 -0.24 c 1.61 -1.55 2.47 -4.66 2.4 -6.65 c -0.18 -0.77 -0.25 -1.48 -0.25 -2.1 c 0 -0.35 0.02 -0.66 0.06 -0.94 c -2.87 2.75 -6.71 5.58 -9.89 8.99 c -0.29 0.81 -0.83 2.41 -0.83 4.34 c 0 2.52 0.9 5.57 4.47 8.13 l -0.2 0.28 c -3.66 -2.62 -4.62 -5.81 -4.61 -8.41 c 0 -1.5 0.32 -2.81 0.6 -3.71 c -2 2.25 -3.67 4.77 -4.57 7.67 l -0.49 -0.15 c 1.8 -5.75 6.45 -9.95 10.72 -13.6 c -1.38 0.4 -4.33 1.33 -6.14 1.1 c -0.89 -0.12 -2.15 -0.33 -3.32 -0.33 c -1.01 0 -1.95 0.15 -2.53 0.59 l -0.2 -0.27 c 0.69 -0.51 1.69 -0.66 2.73 -0.66 c 1.21 0 2.38 0.2 3.37 0.34 c 1.87 0.25 5.49 -0.97 6.7 -1.28 c 2.05 -1.75 3.97 -3.37 5.38 -4.99 c 0.97 -1.1 1.71 -2.38 2.29 -3.71 c -10.41 2.5 -19.7 7.99 -23.78 12.22 c 0.62 -2.6 11.25 -10.16 24.14 -13.15 c 1.65 -4.55 1.49 -9.49 1.56 -10.6 l 0.51 0.03 c -0.08 1.04 0.1 5.85 -1.49 10.44 c 1.43 -0.31 2.88 -0.57 4.35 -0.75 c -0.47 -0.91 -1.94 -4.08 -1.93 -8.09 c 0.08 1.25 1.13 6.08 3.73 7.89 c 6.37 -0.55 12.96 0.31 18.91 3.59 l -0.06 0.83 z};
    \fill[col2] svg {M 102.92 92.63 c 0.07 -1.05 -0.71 -1.96 -1.77 -2.03 c -1.05 -0.07 -1.96 0.71 -2.03 1.76 c -0.08 1.05 0.71 1.96 1.76 2.03 c 1.05 0.07 1.96 -0.71 2.04 -1.76};
    \fill[col3] svg {M 103.12 82.98 c 0.09 -1.26 -0.86 -2.35 -2.11 -2.44 c -1.26 -0.09 -2.35 0.86 -2.44 2.12 c -0.09 1.26 0.86 2.35 2.11 2.44 c 1.26 0.09 2.35 -0.86 2.44 -2.12};
    \fill[col4] svg {M 112.19 96.58 c 0.09 -1.26 -0.86 -2.35 -2.11 -2.44 c -1.26 -0.09 -2.35 0.86 -2.44 2.11 c -0.09 1.26 0.86 2.35 2.12 2.44 c 1.26 0.09 2.35 -0.86 2.43 -2.11};
    \fill[col5] svg {M 117.82 87.1 c 0.17 -2.36 -1.61 -4.4 -3.97 -4.57 c -2.36 -0.17 -4.4 1.61 -4.57 3.96 c -0.17 2.36 1.61 4.4 3.97 4.57 c 2.36 0.17 4.4 -1.61 4.57 -3.96};
    \fill[col6] svg {M 136.13 73.84 c 0.07 -1.05 -0.71 -1.96 -1.76 -2.04 c -1.05 -0.07 -1.96 0.71 -2.03 1.77 c -0.07 1.05 0.71 1.96 1.76 2.03 c 1.05 0.08 1.96 -0.71 2.03 -1.76};
    \fill[col7] svg {M 140.04 75.45 c 0.05 -0.76 -0.52 -1.41 -1.28 -1.47 c -0.76 -0.05 -1.42 0.52 -1.46 1.28 c -0.06 0.76 0.52 1.41 1.27 1.46 c 0.76 0.06 1.41 -0.52 1.47 -1.27};
    \fill[col8] svg {M 112.44 77.64 c 0.05 -0.76 -0.52 -1.41 -1.27 -1.46 c -0.76 -0.05 -1.42 0.52 -1.47 1.27 c -0.05 0.76 0.52 1.41 1.27 1.47 c 0.76 0.05 1.41 -0.52 1.47 -1.28};
    \fill[col9] svg {M 140.97 83.72 c 0.11 -1.51 -1.03 -2.82 -2.54 -2.93 c -1.51 -0.11 -2.82 1.03 -2.92 2.54 c -0.11 1.51 1.03 2.82 2.53 2.93 c 1.51 0.11 2.82 -1.03 2.93 -2.54};
    \fill[col10] svg {M 128.31 80.1 c 0.07 -1.05 -0.71 -1.96 -1.76 -2.03 c -1.05 -0.08 -1.96 0.71 -2.03 1.76 c -0.08 1.05 0.71 1.96 1.76 2.03 c 1.05 0.07 1.96 -0.71 2.03 -1.76};
    \fill[col11] svg {M 134.05 82.5 c 0.07 -1.05 -0.71 -1.96 -1.76 -2.03 c -1.05 -0.08 -1.96 0.71 -2.03 1.76 c -0.07 1.05 0.71 1.96 1.76 2.03 c 1.05 0.07 1.96 -0.71 2.03 -1.76};
    \fill[col12] svg {M 145.23 78.25 c 0.07 -1.05 -0.71 -1.96 -1.76 -2.03 c -1.05 -0.07 -1.96 0.71 -2.03 1.76 c -0.07 1.05 0.71 1.96 1.76 2.03 c 1.05 0.07 1.96 -0.71 2.03 -1.76};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** There are 11 circles that are approximated by Bezier curves and should be replaced by simple `circle` instructions. Only the first path should be as it is.

**Edit:** Here is the optimized version (with circles, combined colors and shorter svg path).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}
  % les couleurs
  \definecolor{gris}{HTML}{3F464D}
  \definecolor{vertf}{HTML}{00A650}
  \definecolor{vertc}{HTML}{66C430}
  \definecolor{orange}{HTML}{F68712}
  \definecolor{rose}{HTML}{EC086D}
  \definecolor{bleu}{HTML}{35B6ED}
  % le logo
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gris,scale={1mm/1pt}] svg{M146.14 73.32c-3.82-2.19-8.01-3.31-12.31-3.65 1.04 .6 2.55 1.67 3.67 3.08 1.11 .39 4.08 1.34 6.2 3.86l-.25 .21c-1.81-2.14-4.26-3.12-5.59-3.59 .44 .64 .79 1.34 .97 2.08l-.33 .08c-.2-.84-.64-1.64-1.2-2.35-1.36-1.73-3.39-3-4.28-3.42-2.36-.13-4.75-.03-7.12 .26 .2 .8 .78 2.27 2.61 3.73 2.4 1.91 6.96 3.79 15.64 4.05l-.01 .34c-2.63-.08-4.89-.31-6.83-.64 0 .37-.03 .68-.05 .83-.04 .26-.24 1.17 .58 2.55 .32 .53 .64 .88 .63 .87l-.24 .23c-.01-.01-1-1.08-1.29-2.4-.66 1.9-2.26 3.75-5.08 4.35l-.07-.33c4.37-.93 5.25-4.67 5.17-6.17-4.29-.78-6.98-2.08-8.67-3.42-.22-.17-.42-.35-.6-.52 .4 .89 .81 2.13 .81 3.63 0 1.28-.3 2.75-1.15 4.37l-.3-.16c.83-1.57 1.11-2.98 1.12-4.21 0-2.09-.83-3.64-1.26-4.46-.86-1.05-1.21-2.01-1.35-2.6-1.6 .21-3.2 .49-4.77 .85-.19 .47-.4 .94-.64 1.4 .31 4.12 1.08 10.07 6.64 13.81l-.18 .28c-5.46-3.68-6.41-9.43-6.75-13.54-.45 .79-.96 1.54-1.58 2.23-.37 .41-.76 .83-1.18 1.25-.06 .36-.11 .81-.11 1.32 0 1.16 .24 2.66 1.1 4.32 1.19 2.3 3.04 5.65 3.05 7.9 0 .42-.07 .81-.22 1.15l-.3-.14c.13-.28 .19-.62 .19-1.01 0-.76-.24-1.68-.6-2.66v.12c.01 1.85-.99 2.76-2.02 3.46-1.04 .71-2.08 1.29-2.42 2.39-.9 2.94-2.35 3.8-3.17 4.74l-.25-.23c.86-.92 2.32-1.95 3.11-4.64 .36-1.22 1.45-1.79 2.54-2.53 1.01-.7 1.87-1.48 1.87-3.19 0-.34-.04-.72-.14-1.3-.6-1.37-1.34-2.77-1.93-3.9-.24-.47-.44-.92-.6-1.37-.15 1.74-.93 4.38-2.46 5.88l-.24-.24c1.61-1.55 2.47-4.66 2.4-6.65-.18-.77-.25-1.48-.25-2.1 0-.35 .02-.66 .06-.94-2.87 2.75-6.71 5.58-9.89 8.99-.29 .81-.83 2.41-.83 4.34 0 2.52 .9 5.57 4.47 8.13l-.2 .28c-3.66-2.62-4.62-5.81-4.61-8.41 0-1.5 .32-2.81 .6-3.71-2 2.25-3.67 4.77-4.57 7.67l-.49-.15c1.8-5.75 6.45-9.95 10.72-13.6-1.38 .4-4.33 1.33-6.14 1.1-.89-.12-2.15-.33-3.32-.33-1.01 0-1.95 .15-2.53 .59l-.2-.27c.69-.51 1.69-.66 2.73-.66 1.21 0 2.38 .2 3.37 .34 1.87 .25 5.49-.97 6.7-1.28 2.05-1.75 3.97-3.37 5.38-4.99 .97-1.1 1.71-2.38 2.29-3.71-10.41 2.5-19.7 7.99-23.78 12.22 .62-2.6 11.25-10.16 24.14-13.15 1.65-4.55 1.49-9.49 1.56-10.6l.51 .03c-.08 1.04 .1 5.85-1.49 10.44 1.43-.31 2.88-.57 4.35-.75-.47-.91-1.94-4.08-1.93-8.09 .08 1.25 1.13 6.08 3.73 7.89 6.37-.55 12.96 .31 18.91 3.59l-.06 .83z};
    \fill[gris](10.992,9.641) circle(.228) (13.824,8.352) circle(.274);
    \fill[vertf](14.334,7.811) circle(.19) (10.085,8.282) circle(.228) (13.424,7.37) circle(.19);
    \fill[vertc](11.355,8.68) circle(.428);
    \fill[orange](10.102,9.25) circle(.19) (13.867,7.535) circle(.137);
    \fill[rose](13.216,8.236) circle(.19) (11.107,7.755) circle(.137);
    \fill[bleu](12.641,7.996) circle(.19);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Than you I'm sorry I've not seen that before you are great !